# Good link checking tool?

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink

Can anyone recommend a good, free link checker to check all pages within a domain? Ideally a browser add-on or a web app (otherwise something that runs on OSX).

Crucially it needs to follow links recursively *within a domain*. Links outside the domain should be followed to a depth of 1, but not checked recursively.

This is for the fairly common situation where you want to check all pages on your own site, but not evaluate the links on e.g. Google's homepage.

I can't find anything suitable. Am I missing something?

I've tried the Firefox [LinkChecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/532) add-on and the [W3C link validator](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) - neither seem to have the 'follow recursively *within a domain*' property, or am I being dumb?

I know [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) does this, but I don't run Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3C offering does only check to a depth of 1 when it leaves the domain.

Comment: Oh, great. (It would be better if that was more obvious!)